# Define an EPL statement that triggers an event based on properties of elements in a collection

Tags: esper

I have objects that point to collections of elements. What I want to do is define an EPL statement that triggers an event for each of the objects containing at least one of those elements in the collection satisfying some condition. Something like this:

```
insert into SomeComplexEvent 
select SomeObjectID
from
    SomeObject as obj
where 
    exists elem in obj.elemsCollection where elem.attribute = someValue;
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes something like "elemsCollection.anyOf(v => v.attribute=someValue)".

http://espertech.com/esper/release-5.3.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#enumerationreference